# /complete/email does not exist in python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, authentication, python-social-auth

I am using [python-social-auth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/) for login feature.

I added facebook and instagram logins. Now I am trying to do a standard authentication with email.

[Documentation](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/email.html) says that my login form should submit to `/complete/email`.

But when I submit it says that `Page was not found`

what am I doing wrong? maybe documentation is out of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it was a very stupid mistake of mine:

Just add `'social.backends.email.EmailAuth'` to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS.

Comment: @Yeo I am not allowed to now. After 2 days